# If $x\in dom(\phi),$ we can use the code $\Phi$ and minimization theorem to prove within $RCA_0$ that $\phi(x)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, logic, continuity, reverse-math

Currently I am reading [Simpson's Subsystem of Second Order Arithmetic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/subsystems-of-second-order-arithmetic/EA16CB4305831530B7015D6BC46B7424).

The author defined continuous function as follows:

> Within $RCA_0,$ let $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ be complete separable metric spaces. 
>   A (code for a ) continuous partial function $\phi$ from $\hat{A}$ to $\hat{B}$ is a set of quintuple $\Phi\subseteq \mathbb{N}\times A\times \mathbb{Q}^+ \times B\times \mathbb{Q}^+ $ which is required to have certain properties.
>   We write $(a,r)\Phi (b,s)$ as an abbreviation for $\exists n ((n,a,r,b,s)\in \Phi).$
>   The properties which we require are:
>
> 1. if $(a,r)\Phi (b,s)$ and $(a,r)\Phi (b',s'),$ then $d(b,b')\leq s+s';$
> 2. if $(a,r)\Phi (b,s)$ and $(a',r') < (a,r),$ then $(a',r')\Phi(b,s);$
> 3. if $(a,r)\Phi (b,s)$ and $(b,s) < (b',s'),$ then $(a',r')\Phi(b',s');$
>
> where the notation $(a',r')<(a,r)$ means that $d(a,a')+r'<r.$

Then the authors stated the following in the next paragraph.

> If $x\in dom(\phi),$ we define the value $\phi(x)$ to be the unique point $y\in \hat{B}$ such that $d(y,b)\leq s$ for all $(a,r)\Phi(b,s)$ with $d(x,)<r.$

The author continue with the following statement.

> **If $x\in dom(\phi),$ we can use the code $\Phi$ and minimization theorem to prove within $RCA_0$ that $\phi(x)$ exists.**

I have trouble proving $\phi(x)$ exists. 
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: At a glance, you seem to be assuming $x$ belongs to the "domain" of $\phi$.  But what is $\phi$?  If it were known that $\phi$ is a function, then by definition $\phi(x)$ exists.  So apparently you mean to assume something weaker about the nature of $phi$, referring to it at one point as a "continuous partial function".

Comment: @hardmath: the answer is that $\Phi$ is a code for a continuous function. The definition of $\text{dom}(\Phi)$ is not in the question, although it is in the source. To prove that "within $\mathsf{RCA}_0$"  that $\phi(x)$ exists has a specific and formal meaning - it means to prove in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ that there is a unique real $y$ that satisfies the condition mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is the definition of "$x \in \text{dom}(\Phi)$."

You want to view $(a,r)\Phi(b,s)$ as saying that if $x \in (a-r, a+r)$ then $\phi(x) \in [b-s, b+s]$.  By definition (not in the question), $x \in \text{dom}(\Phi)$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have $(a,r)\Phi(b,s)$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, some $s \leq \epsilon$ and so that $d(a,x) < r$.

If we apply this with $\epsilon = 2^{-k}$ we can get a rational $b_k$ so that $d(b_k, \phi(x)) \leq 2^{-k}$.  We can choose $b_k$ by searching for an $m$ so that $(m, a, r, b, s)$ is in $\Phi$ and verifies the last sentence of the previous paragraph - this is a computable search, and this process is what Simpson means by "using minimization".

The resulting sequence $(b_k)$ is $\Delta^0_1$ in $x$ and $\phi$, and $(b_k)$ will be a quickly converging Cauchy sequence that converges to $\phi(x)$.